# Forming Squares or Rectangles from a Group of Squares and/or Rectangles Problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Please see the problem below:

[image]

If, as the problem says, all it needs is for the group of figures to form either a square OR a rectangle, then doesn't all 4 choices allow you to form either a rectangle or square?

In the answer key though, it says that the answer is (C).  However, can't the figures in (C) form a rectangle in this formation:

B B S 
B B S

where B stands for the bigger rectangle and and S is the smaller rectangle?

We are quite confused with this and would appreciate any help.  Thanks

Comment: The answer is $A$. You are right about $C$. Personally, I distrust answer keys as they are rarely perfect.

Comment: What are the side lengths of each rectangle?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply.  But can't the figures in letter A also form a big rectangle as you can stack those 2 thin horizontal pieces on top of each other?  No side lengths were given too

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. For $C$ there are  many solutions, for example $SBBBBS$ would work as well. However it seems that $A$ is problematic unless the middle sized rectangles can cover the length of the longer one.